# jquery expanded bar widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need a expand bar widget(jquery/js/html/css) like this:
[image]

I can not find anything close.
Who knows similar widget?

P.S. Expanded bar is not accordion.
 In Expanded bar you can open "Expanded Item Title 1" and "Expanded Item Title 2".
 In accordion you can open only "Expanded Item Title 1" or "Expanded Item Title 2".

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like bootstrap-collapse from twitter bootstrap, but you will have to define your own css styles to get same look & feel.
See here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: So it's easy, with jquery, juste call slideToggle function when you click on an item.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is commonly referred to as an **accordion**, and the reference implementation for this in **jQuery** can be found at the following location:

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Expanded bar is not accordion.
In Expanded bar you can open "Expanded Item Title 1" and "Expanded Item Title 2".
In accordion you can open only "Expanded Item Title 1" or "Expanded Item Title 2".

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean now. Obviously, your static image example did not demonstrate this behaviour.

Comment: The whole point of this widget, though, is to group a large amount of data into a small space. If you have room to display all panels at once, why bother collapsing them at all?